# Define Typescript type for req.body node/express backend

Tags: typescript

Kind of new to typescript here and starting to get a bit of a hang of it. I have a route on an express backend that gets data from `req.body`, `{email, password} = req.body`.

The `User.build({email, password})` is expecting a string type for both email and password, as I set this within an interface called `IUser` in the model/schema file, but it reading the "any" type when getting `email` and `password` from `req.body`. Code below -- My question is how do I tell my `User.build` method that the `email` and `password` are going to be strings for sure?

Route:

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);

  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const newUser = User.build({ email, password });
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, async (err, hash) => {
      try {
        newUser.password = hash;
        const items = await newUser.save();
        res.json({
          success: "POST USER",
          message: "Registered new user.",
          items,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.json({
          error: "An account with this email already exists.",
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Error

```
Argument of type '{ email: any; password: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IUser'.
```

Comment: I am currently going to try importing the `IUser` interface, assigning req.body the type of IUser in a variable, and passing the variable into the `build` function.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by providing `Type Parameters` to the route builder.

`router.METHOD()` accepts type parameters to explicit the types of the arguments inside the callback. The type parameters are defined in this order

1. ParamsDictionary
2. ResponseBody
3. RequestBody
4. RequestQuery
5. Locals

By defining their types with `router.post<type_1, type_2, ...>` their types inside the callback will now have the type you passed instead of their defaults.

```
import { ParamsDictionary } from 'express-serve-static-core';

type CredentialsRequestBody = { email: string, password: string };

router.post<
    ParamsDictionary, 
    any /* Or the type you want your response body to be */, 
    CredentialsRequestBody 
    /* here you can define the remaining types */>("/register", async (req, res) => {


const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);

  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const newUser = User.build({ email, password });
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, async (err, hash) => {
      try {
        newUser.password = hash;
        const items = await newUser.save();
        res.json({
          success: "POST USER",
          message: "Registered new user.",
          items,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.json({
          error: "An account with this email already exists.",
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```